# Caixa de texto para determinar quantidade de uso de digito

Tags: c#, textbox, teclado

Abaixo segue o código que estou tentando limitar o uso de letras na caixa de texto, a exceção da virgula, mas ocorre que a virgula pode ser digitada centena de vez, gostaria que a virgula fosse usada apenas uma vez. Como é o correto?

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9') || e.KeyChar == ',')
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode adicionar mais uma validação

```
textBox1.Text.Count(letra => letra == ',') > 1
```

Se essa condição for verdadeira, o `e.Handled` deveria ser `true`, para que não escrevesse a vírgula.

Por tratar o evento `KeyPress`, saiba que ainda se pode copiar e colar valores dentro do TextBox, independente do caractere.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos que contribuirão, serviram para rever meu código, e acabei mudando ele para:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) ) 

            e.Handled = true; 

        if (e.KeyChar == ',' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(',') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```